# ConstraintLayout: How to exclude child from wrap_content calculations

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Consider this simple **ConstraintLayout** `content_main.xml` where one `View` is "regular" and the other `View` is conceptually part of an animated background, while still being layout relative to the regular `View`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000">

    <!--LinearLayout    Fixes 'wrap_content' but breaks positioning
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"-->

    <View
            android:id="@+id/shouldBeExcludedFromWrapContent"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/partOfWrapContent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/partOfWrapContent"
            android:background="@android:drawable/star_big_on" />

    <!--/LinearLayout-->

    <View
            android:id="@+id/partOfWrapContent"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:background="@android:drawable/sym_action_call" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

with the following in `MainActivity.onCreate()`:

```
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main)
        findViewById<View>(R.id.shouldBeExcludedFromWrapContent)
            .animate()
            .rotationBy(5 * 360f)
            .translationXBy(-900f)
            .translationYBy(-900f)
            .setDuration(5_000L)
            .start()
```

it results in the following animation (both with `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3` and `2.0.0-beta4`):

[image: actual result]

## Question

How can I make the `wrap_content` calculation ignore `@id/shouldBeExcludedFromWrapContent`? I want it to be clipped by its parent, so the end result is like this:

[image: expected]

## Note:

- It is **crucial** that the animated view is layout **relative to its sibling** via the `ConstraintLayout` (The parenting hack I exemplified above is not an option. In the real code, the relationships are much more complex, and can not be approximated or duplicated)
- `android:layout_height` must be `wrap_content`, because the real layout has dynamic content/height and is part of a `ScrollView`

## Accepting answer

Must either be

- a reference to an authoritative source saying it is not supported (such as a reference to the official issue tracker for `ConstraintLayout` where this has been discussed, or a reference to the `ConstraintLayout` source code), or
- a solution to the problem formulated in the title (or equivalent)

Comment: why your shouldBeExcludedFromWrapContent view height has to be 100dp?

Comment: @MdGolamRahmanTushar In the real code there are 15 or so of those views that together make up the "background" for the ConstraintLayout.

Comment: but at the end  you want your constraint viewgroup height to be equal to the partOfWrapContent view, right?

Comment: Why can't they both have a height of 40dp?

Comment: @MdGolamRahmanTushar yes

Comment: @Raimo Because the visual effect shall be clipping. And it is animated in a way so that the whole 100dp is revealed during the animatino, i.e. it is not enough to "fake" clipping.

Comment: then try the solution I provided in the answer!

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add this for your `shouldBeExcludedFromWrapContent` view.

```
    android:translationX="100dp"
    android:translationY="100dp"
```

And update your constraints as like this. This is the reason your viewgroup is taking unnecessary space.

```
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/partOfWrapContent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/partOfWrapContent"
```

to

```
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/partOfWrapContent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/partOfWrapContent"
```

Hope this can help you. Good luck. ;)

Comment: Interesting! That works even if I change both width and height of `@id/shouldBeExcludedFromWrapContent` to `400dp`! But it is not a generic solution because it does not work if layout relative to top left corner, like this: `android:layout_width/height="400dp" android:translationX/Y="-400dp" app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/partOfWrapContent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/partOfWrapContent"` But you deserve credit for a nice example-specific workaround!

Comment: hmm, sry if it doesn't work for prob. But from what I see, it's still working. But of coz you need to update ur animation attributes.

Comment: If it's not what you want, can u let me know what is your use case and requirement?

Comment: I'm after a generic solution, sorry if that is not clear from the question. For example, can you get your solution to work in the following case? https://gist.github.com/Enselic/467b809c98c2cb146925edc29eb0f281 In this case, `@id/shouldBeExcludedFromWrapContent` is larger than `@id/partOfWrapContent` and layout in the top left corner instead of bottom right corner, with animation direction reversed. In this gist, `@id/shouldBeExcludedFromWrapContent` still affects `wrap_content` calculations.

Comment: You came closest to a solution, and it seems wasteful to flush 100 rep down the drain. So I'll give you the 100 rep bounty. Congrats :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but this might be the solution you are looking for. Except the partOfWrapContent view make all the child of constraint layout height match_parent. Thus the contraint layout would get the height of partOfWrapContent view. This might solve your problem. Hope it helps.

Update: try setting a max height to constraint layout like below:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintHeight_max="40dp"
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
```

Comment: Sorry no that won't work. Due to the way the view is animated, it is necessary to do real clipping, i.e. it is not possible to fake it.

Comment: you mean for example for the shouldBeExcludedFromWrapContent view the whole 100dp would be scrollable inside the 40dp height, right?

Comment: Yes that would be one way to put it, that the 100dp "scrolls" inside the 40dp. But not scroll using ScrollView, but "scroll" through animation.

Comment: @Enselic I have added another possible solution to the answer using max height. Plz check!

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but what you propose is effectively "fake" clipping. I.e. since the view Y position is animated, one will be able to see that the clipping effect is faked.

Comment: For the record, constraining height is not an option since that counteracts wrap_content which is essential for my use case

Answer (score 0):

I would create one main layout that will have "match_parent" or similar size. In that layout you can have 2 children:

1. The ConstraintLayout with wrap content.
2. The View with the star

In this case the star view will be excluded from the ConstraintLayout wrap content.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, but I think you missed this part in the question: "It is crucial that the animated view is layout relative to its sibling via the ConstraintLayout"

Answer (score 0):

Try modify shouldBeExcludedFromWrapContent's constraint like this.

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/partOfWrapContent"  
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/partOfWrapContent"
```

to

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"  
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
```

Comment: Interesting. That indeed makes `wrap_content` skip `@id/shouldBeExcludedFromWrapContent`. However, even if it is a good workaround for the example in the question, it does not fulfill the following requirement postulated in the question: "It is crucial that the animated view is layout relative to its sibling via the ConstraintLayout", which is necessary in order for me to be able to use it in my real code. But it certainly is a step in the right direction!

Comment: Sibling is "shouldBeExcludedFromWrapContent" and "partOfWrapContent" right?
I think sibling is not layout relatived. But in this case it doesn't seem necessary.
Would you explain why sibling need layout relative? What kind of relative is needed(top_to_bottom? or left_to_right? or else)
*I am sorry that I am not used to English :)

Comment: In the example in the question it is not necessary. But imagine a more complex layout. In such a complex layout, it is necessary to layout relative to siblings.

Answer (score 0):

First of all sorry for my previous answer, I somehow misunderstood what you wanted to achieve and there were some errors in the code as well.

I managed to reproduce what you want and below you see the result.

the code just wraps your code in a Framelayout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:id="@+id/frame">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|start"
    android:background="#000">


<View
    android:id="@+id/shouldBeExcludedFromWrapContent"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/partOfWrapContent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/partOfWrapContent"
    android:background="@android:drawable/star_big_on" />



<View
    android:id="@+id/partOfWrapContent"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:background="@android:drawable/sym_action_call" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

there is one missing step as in this code: the dimensions of the framelayout are hardcoded to 300dp but if I understand correctly you need them to wrap to a `partOfWrapContent` that will vary in size. the fix for that is not super elegant but you can do that in java with the following code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    FrameLayout frame=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame) ;
    View partOfWrapContent=(View) findViewById(R.id.partOfWrapContent);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = frame.getLayoutParams();
    //get the desired size of your drawables in dp and feed it into dipH and dipW
    float dipH = 300f;
    float dipW = 300f;
    Resources r = getResources();
    float pxH = TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            dipH,
            r.getDisplayMetrics()
    );
    float pxW = TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            dipW,
            r.getDisplayMetrics()
    );
    params.height=(int)pxH;
    params.width=(int)pxW;
    frame.setLayoutParams(params);
    findViewById(R.id.shouldBeExcludedFromWrapContent)
            .animate()
            .rotationBy(5 * 360f)
            .translationXBy(-900f)
            .translationYBy(-900f)
            .setDuration(5_000L)
            .start();


}
```

in this code you will have to feed in the size of `partOfWrapContent` which I guess you can get from your drawable resources. With this approach you can have animated objects comming in from anywhere (as long as its the bottom or the right side XD) but I guess you can tweek that a bit by changing `android:layout_gravity="top|start"` (maybe use an oversized contraintlayout and put `partOfWrapContent` in the center, that way your animated objects could come from anywhere) I am not sure if this is dynamic enough for you but maybe it at least gives you some ideas.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write an answer. But I don't quite understand your suggestion. I tried using your code, including with some adjustments, but I could not get it to work. And I don't think your solution is on the right track, because you talk about "use the gravity parameter in CardView to sort of position". I don't want "sort of" positioning. I want full ConstraintLayout capable positioning.

Comment: @Enselic, sorry, I misunderstood quite a bit before. I found a way to reproduce what you want even if its not super elegant. have a look at my updated answer

Comment: Your updated answer seems to boil down to "instead of wrap_content, manually calculate size of everything". That is not a viable option since my real code has a complex combination of ImageViews and TextViews. And my question clearly states that `wrap_content` must be used.

Comment: well the only thing that I could think of in that case is that you extend the ConstraintLayout.class and override some methods in there to make it set the layout params based only on one of the contained views. but that seems like quite a bit of work